# Fragment loads a Fragment in a linear layout, doesn't apply the weight

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout, android-layout-weight

My problem is:

I have a fragment that loads another fragment using a linear layout with property "weight".

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

But, when the fragment is loaded, it doesn't apply the property weight.
In my second fragment I have the view like so:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity, container, false);
```

What can I do?

Comment: The weight should be applied to the framelayout containing the fragment, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Change orientation from horizontal to vertical, this piece of code will work.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="8" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="0dp"> </LinearLayout>
```